# cpanel can't visit temp url - redirects to http://www.ip/~user/

Tags: ip, cpanel, whm

I'm new to VPS servers and just setting up a test environment to find my way around. I have WHM installed and have just created a new account with cpanel, I want to be able to visit the temp url, i.e. http://IP/~user however, when I visit, my browser adds a www. to the front (http://www.IP/~user/) which brings up a "page cannot be found" error.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here and how I rectify it

Thanks

UPDATE: Here is my htaccess in the root of my public_html file (it's just a standard wordpress multisite htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you have not made changes to the httpd.conf then it is an error cpanel, who added something wrong, because its documentation and its operation is clear. You must go to http: // IP / ~ user. https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Apache+mod_userdir+Tweak

Comment: @abkrim I haven't made any changes to httpd.conf - infact, I've just set this up as a new cpanel on a new VPS. I've also enabled mod_userdir - any other thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Something's not right, and I think may be a bug.I suppose you have deleted browser cookies before proceeding. As I say, the mod_userdir, it is clear ... ip / ~ user, hostanme / ~ user and no redirection. Attention: what has the .htacess site you're looking at? You may have a redirect to www. Run on site's puvlic_html > cat .htaccess |grep www

Comment: @abkrim added my htaccess from public_html - not seeing anything strange in there though that would do this

Comment: Yopur problem ot's worpress configuration. Ther're any config redirect to www. Please put a index.html on your site and test this file.

Comment: Aha, we're getting somewhere - http://166.62.89.210/~effyeah/index.html this works. So is the issue with wordpress?

Comment: Yes.. Issue it's on WP. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL or http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-introduction/installing-wordpress-using-your-temporary-url Best if you test your sites using /etc/hosts file for put a develop IP, instead using wrong IP/~user

Comment: amazing, thanks for your help on this @abkrim

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `mod_userdir` from WHM backend